# Using multiple detail views with TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to implement a table view page within my tabbed bar application. I have successfully made a table view containing data, and I want this to take me to a detail view. However I want separate detail views for each Cell, to allow me to create more detailed detail views using the UI. I have given the Seque's unique IDs to try and do this.

Currently it crashed every time I press the button, taking me to main.m

Here is the code I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail1" sender:self];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail2" sender:self];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail3" sender:self];
            break;
        case 3:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail4" sender:self];
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
}
```

The exception I get is:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'showDetail2'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'"

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the exact exception that occurs?

Comment: I've edited the original post, still not sure how to go about fixing it after looking at exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ViewController` where you have added your `tableView`, should be a part of a `NavigationController`. A `ViewController` can only be pushed if it is a part of `NavigationController`. Else try using `Present Segue`.

**Solution 1:**

Make your present `ViewController` in which you have added your `tableView` a part of `NavigationController`

If you are using `StoryBoard`, then select your `ViewController` in which you have added the tableView. With the Controller selected, choose **Editor\Embed In\Navigation Controller**

**Solution 2:**

If you do not want to use `Navigation/Push` design then you can present the `ViewController`. For that you have to use `Present Segues`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the VC with the TableView in it is actually connected to my tab bar controller, so I dont know how to add it to another navigation controller as well... thanks

Comment: Well add your VC to a Navigation Controller as steps shown in my answer and then embed this navigation controller to your tab bar controller. Let me know if it worked.