# Push segue from ViewController to a TableViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a normal ViewController which i have added a button to make a push segue to a table view controller. I have a tab bar in my application and i need to keep it in all views. But when i make the segue while running the app i get the following error.

```
SGenericException Reason: Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'View'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.
```

I have searched and found that i have to embed in navigation controller and i did. But i still get that error. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating the segue while the app is running. If you add a segue on view controller to table view controller it will automatically push. You dont have to create it.

Comment: I mean that i when i try to press the button while running the app to transfer me into the table view, that i have connected with a push segue from the storyboard, then i am getting that error. In my storyboard i just connected the button from the previous view controller with the tableviewcontroller without any code. Just added the type of segue.

Comment: Have you added a uinavigationcontroller with the view controller? I guess you are having the view controller without a navigation controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130834/using-multiple-detail-views-with-tableview/29131194#29131194

Comment: This is my storyboard view : http://postimg.org/image/73vdj85j1/ My view controller is part of the tabbar. I can't add a navigation controller in my viewcontroller

Comment: @user3882720 Kindly see the link posted and comments below the answer. Add your VC to a Navigation Controller as steps shown in my answer and then embed this navigation controller to your tab bar controller

Comment: Correct check the link given by @Burhanuddin Sunelwala

Comment: I have already done that. My viewcontroller that has the table view is part of NavigationController.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  [Jassi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193918/jassi) you were right. I had just to add in the first view controller a navigationController. And that was just what i did. I embed in my firstviewcontroller a navigationcontroller and just did the push segue. I didn't embed a navigation controller in the view that has the tableview. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough information to go on, have you tried popover instead of push?
You need a navigationController to 'push' a view

Comment: No i just tried the modal view. I need to keep my tab bar visible in every next view controller. That's why i try it with push. My viewController as i have mentioned is part of tabbar. So i can't embed in a navigation controller.

Comment: set the button as the anchor for a popover, shouldn't affect the tabBar as it pops up in the current view.

Comment: Try doing this. The first view controller you are adding, Add it in a navigation controller with root view. Then dont add another nav controller. You will still have tab bar.

Comment: In every segue i try, push, popover i get the same error. Only with modal i get no error and i can continue. The only issue with modal is that i am not able to keep my tab bar.